# Speaker comparison for desktop

Tags: speakers

I'm going to try and make this so the answer is not based on opinion.

I have a desktop computer that I use for a variety of tasks: web browsing, video editing, video gaming, university projects, software development, listening to music, etc. I recently dropped my [old pair of cheap speakers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BXF5HQ8), and figured it was time for an upgrade.

I am looking for a pair of desktop/bookshelf speakers. I would like to spend less than $100-150. Now, I know that there are thousands of options in this price range, but I would like to narrow it down to two. I am either thinking of either the [Edifier R1280T](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016P9HJIA) or the [Mackie CR4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KVEIY4E). I would appreciate a recommendation, if anyone has experience with these two *specific* models, for which speaker would work best for my needs. I do not know enough about audio equipment to see the pros and cons of each of these two models, and would appreciate any advice you can give me. I am also open to other suggestions, but these are the two I am primarily looking at. Here are a few things I would like to have in my new speakers, and what I am considering:

- hard budget of $100-150 ($150 max)
- studio quality (for the price range)
- clean aesthetics (basic form factor, nothing crazy)
- RCA input

Can anyone recommend which of these two speakers better fits the above requirements? I appreciate opinions, but I would like to keep this on-topic for this website, by rating which of the two has better sound quality, which has better bang-for-buck value, etc. I am more looking for metrics and values that can be measured, rather than just *I like this one more than that one*.

Comment: @0-60FPS I looked into the Logitech and they do look like a good option, but they are not that much different from my old audio system (see link in question). I will keep them in mind, but I am hoping for something a little bit nicer

Comment: Are you specifically looking for powered speakers, or is a set-up that includes an amp and speaker wire acceptable, so long as it stays within your budget?

Comment: @cjm I was more looking for powered speakers (just because I figured I'd get a better bang for my buck), but I'm really open to anything under $150 if you know something better

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with the two models you mentioned. But, I'd recommend the Logitech z313 2.1 system. It goes for about $50. Logitech's website has some fairly detailed specs. It does use 3.5mm so you will need an adapter. I've had mine for about 2 years and it works very well. Something to consider I guess.

You could also take a look at Logitech's Z623 2.1 system. 400W total, and it does have an RCA input (It can take 3.5mm also). Goes for $150 on Logitech's website and for about $130 on Amazon.

Hope this helps!

0-60FPS